# Sitefinity 9.1 HTML re-structure issue in content block

Tags: html, sitefinity

I'm trying to copy some HTML content  to Sitefinity HTML Content Block, Unfortunately the content I copied will get changed everytime I copied in HTML view. I cannot copy the content in to the design view directly, since I have used some jquery and CSS classes which needs to be there in the code.

Below is the original HTMl content,

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="aboutImage">
                        <a href="single-course-right-sidebar.html" class="aboutImage">
                            <img src="/images/home/learn/arts-design.jpg" alt="Arts & Design" class="img-responsive" />
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean consectetur ante volutpat sem aliquam lobortis.</p>
                            </div>
                            <span class="captionLink">Arts & Design</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is the code after I copied,

```html
    
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
<div class="aboutImage">
<a href="single-course-right-sidebar.html">
<img src="/images/home/learn/arts-design.jpg" alt="Fashion" class="img-responsive">
</a>
<div class="overlay">
<a href="single-course-right-sidebar.html"></a>
<p><a href="single-course-right-sidebar.html">TAFE SA fashion courses, help you develop the skills to succeed in the fashion industry.</a></p>
</div>
<a href="single-course-right-sidebar.html">
<span class="captionLink">Fashion</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks and Appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable RadEditor filters for Content Block widget.

1. Got to Settings -> Advanced -> Appearance
2. Find property "RadEditor filters for Content block widget"
3. Put value "None" instead "DefaultFilters"

[image]

Comment: Hey Victor, Perfect !
This is what i want.I'm late to see this answer bcuz of the time different. Thans!